# Taxonomy term not found using tid from term reference

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

The users in my webapplication have a `term reference` **suppliers**.

I also have a `content type` **transaction** where I have the same `term reference`. Now I would like to hide the select list and **set the default value** programmatically. This is what I do now:

```
$form['field_supplier']['#type'] = 'hidden';
$user_suppliers = array();

foreach($user_selling->field_suppliers['und'] as $supplier)
{
    $user_suppliers[] = $supplier['tid'];
}

$firstsupplier = reset($user_suppliers);

$first_supplier = taxonomy_term_load($firstsupplier);
```

As you can see I loop through the **tid's** and save them in array. Afterwards I pick the **first** one (there's a reason I don't pick the first instead of looping through).

The `$firstsupplier` variable results **7** so what's not abnormal for a **tid**. But when I want to load the taxonomy term I get a response false... (he can't find it) .

I recently resetted my `taxonomy vocabulary` to **alphabetical**, could that be the reason? (I think not, because I tried it after saving them in a random order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use 'und', you should be using LANGUAGE_NONE instead.

Your code works, so you might have a data inconsistency on your database, are you sure that the term id 7 really exists?

You can use entity api metadata wrappers to access easier to the field information, or if you're not  using Entity API module, the function [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) is a better way to access the information.

```
$user_suppliers = array();
$items = field_get_items('node', $user_selling, 'field_suppliers');

foreach($items as $item) {
    $user_suppliers[] = $item['tid'];
}

$firstsupplier = reset($user_suppliers);
$first_supplier = taxonomy_term_load($firstsupplier);
```

Comment: When I load the items I get the same result (same tids). When I check for them in the database they're not there. (The tid's should be different ... The supplier is in the database but wrong tid)